# NotificationListener - Check if notification was removed by user

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I work with `NotificationListener` and I have a question.

Can I figure out if a notification was removed by the user and not by the app?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean cleared by the user from the notification drawer. Yes you can get this information using [setDeleteIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent))

The above mentioned API triggers a callback when the notification is cleared.

```
Intent finalIntent = new Intent(context, PushWorker.class);
    finalIntent.putExtras(extras);
    finalIntent.setAction(MoEPushWorker.NOTIFICATION_CLEARED);
    PendingIntent intent =
        PendingIntent.getService(context,  123, finalIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setDeleteIntent(intent);
```

Here PushWorker is the service in which the callback will be received.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how it can help?

Comment: But this service will receive callback even when app removes a notification, I think it can't help me to determine if user remove the notification.

Comment: Please read the documentation, clearly states " this intent is sent when the user clicks the "Clear all" button, or the individual "X" buttons on notifications. This intent is not sent when the application calls"